# Unity 3d project apk file is getting installed but not running?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I deleted some textures and images, which i dont use from assets. And apk file which I build started to dont work. I can install to phone ( note 2 ) but it is not running. I can not see it in applications. only I can uninstall it. 
I changed player settings and did not worked, I built for web and it works fine, I looked to android manifest xml and it is same with working apk which is old version.
Thank you for help.
my manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="auto">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity">
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>

  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: When you say that it doesn't run, what happens when you click on the app's icon?

Comment: problem is there is no where i can click :) 1. run the apk. 2. install the application. 3. after install, the run button is hide.. and i can not see it in the aplications. i can see in the application manangment and i can uninstall it.

Comment: Still i am working on Android Manifest. I guess, the problem is in there.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file please?